# What does (beat) refer to in a script and what other elements can we put instead of (beat)?

Tags: script

What does (beat) refer to in a script and what other elements can we put instead of (beat)?

[image]

Right below "It's starting to feel like it", we see (beat), but it's like something outside of the dialogue and I am not sure what's the purpose for it and what other elements we can put aside (beat) in the same location. Can someone tell me what it's used for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A beat is a pause in the dialog.  It indicates he says the first part and then, after a bit, the second.

If you want something to happen between the parts, you put that in.  If not, you want "(beat)".

Comment: If this is a script for a graphic novel or a comic book (which I suspect it might be, since it refers to "panels" and "pages"), then the "beat" might be portrayed by having two connected speech balloons.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates a quick physical gesture of some sort that breaks up the dialogue. I think it probably is used to indicate a break in the scene, a transition from one flow of dialogue to the next, a change in pace.

> In filmmaking, a beat is a small amount of action resulting in a pause
> in dialogue. Beats usually involve physical gestures like a character
> walking to a window or removing their glasses and rubbing their eyes.
> Short passages of internal monologue can also be considered a sort of
> internal beat.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(filmmaking)#:~:text=In%20filmmaking%2C%20a%20beat%20is,a%20sort%20of%20internal%20beat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(filmmaking)#:%7E:text=In%20filmmaking%2C%20a%20beat%20is,a%20sort%20of%20internal%20beat).